# What's the best way to tell if a bus contains a single x in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, test-bench

I have a test bench that monitors a bus.  Some of the signals (bits) within the bus can be 1'bx.  For a variety of reasons, I need to know if any of the signals within the bus are 1'bx.  What's the best way to test (not for synthesis -- only for simulation purposes) if a bus contains any x's?  I had hoped that I could use a reduction OR and then use `===`, but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`(^bus === 1'bX)`

Bit-wise xor the bus then check if the result is X. If any bit is X or Z then the result will be X.

To know which bit in the bus has the error:

```
always @* begin
  for(integer i=0; i<$size(bus); i++) begin
     if(bus[i]===1'bX) $display("bus[%0d] is X",bus[i]);
     if(bus[i]===1'bZ) $display("bus[%0d] is Z",bus[i]);
  end
end
```

Comment: The bit-wise xor will check the entire bus, but it will not say where in the bus the X or Z exists. It is is useful if you do not care to know the location of the X or Z.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `$isunknown` (refer to the IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 20.9 *Bit vector system functions*):

```
module tb;

reg [3:0] data;

initial begin
    #5 data = 4'b0101;
    #5 data = 4'b000x;
    #5 data = 4'b1111;
    #5 data = 4'b0x0x;
    #5 data = 4'b0x1x;
    #5 data = 4'bzzzz;
    #5 $finish;
end

always @(data) begin
    if ($isunknown(data)) $display($time, " data=%b has x's", data);
end

endmodule
```

Outputs:

```
                  10 data=000x has x's
                  20 data=0x0x has x's
                  25 data=0x1x has x's
                  30 data=zzzz has x's
```

Note that this also treats `z` as `x`.